# Whitelabel Error in Java Spring Web Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a Java web application using Spring Tools that takes in a file path as a query parameter and returns the files at that given file path. However, I am getting a Whitelabel error when I run the application. I'm not sure if the issue is from the way I'm calling `Filewalk.java` or if it's because of an issue with how I'm formatting the request. I am new to Spring Tools and would appreciate anybody taking a look at my code and letting me know where I'm going wrong:

**SpringBootExampleApplication.java**

```java
package net.javavatutorial.tutorials;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootExampleApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/file")
    @ResponseBody
    public String home(@RequestParam("filepath") String filepath) { 
        return Filewalk.filewalk(filepath);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Filewalk.java** program that finds the files at a given file path:

```java
package net.javavatutorial.tutorials;

import java.io.File; 

public class Filewalk {
    
    public static String filewalk(String s) {
        String result = "";
        // creates a file object
        File file = new File(s);
        
        // returns an array of all files
        String[] fileList = file.list();
        
        for (String str : fileList) {
            result += str + "\n";
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an error to your question. I checked your code, it works without error. You may not be calling the endpoint correctly. I've tried calling the endpoint with a check like this: "curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/file?filepath=/Users/name/Downloads'"

Comment: @V.Mokrecov Turns out it was an issue with the format and when I wrote the request like yours it worked fine, thank you so much!!!